# Differentiation to Integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Suppose we have the following relation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=v$$
Then how does this imply the following:
$$\int_{t_0}^{t} v\,dt=\int_{x_0}^xdx$$

The differentials cannot be treated as numbers since they are operators, then how do we come about the above relationship? Any detailed proof is highly appreciable.

I did try searching for a suitable answer on the website, but I couldn't find any. So, please don't mark this question a duplicate.

Comment: The RHS should be position, $x$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you for pointing out the error. It's corrected now.

Comment: The LHS is also wrong since $v$ is a function of $t$ then the limit of integral should be also $t$ or values that denote time.

Comment: The RHS can be integrated, $x-x_o$.

Comment: Because this is a differential equation. Look up differential equation proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof follows directly from the proof of *[Integration by Substitution](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Integration_by_Substitution)* which itself follows from the *[First and Second Fundamental Theorems of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorems_of_calculus#Formal_statements)*. In general putting $x=\mathrm{g}(t)$ gives

$$\int \mathrm{f}(x)~\mathrm{d}x = \int \left(\mathrm{f}\circ\mathrm{g}\right)(t)\cdot\dot{\mathrm{g}}(t)~\mathrm{d}t$$

subject to certain conditions on the functions $\mathrm{f}$ and $\mathrm{g}$.

If we let $\mathrm{f}$ be the identity function, i.e. $\mathrm{f}(x)=1$ for all $x$ and setting $\mathrm{g}(t)=x(t)$ we get

$$\int\mathrm{d}x = \int \dot{x}(t)~\mathrm{d}t=\int v~\mathrm{d}t$$

Take a look at the link that I supplied at the start for a proof and links to other proofs.

A more advanced approach is to notice that things like $\mathrm{f}(x)~\mathrm{d}x$ are [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) and that we are actually integrating differential forms. If $x$ is a function of $t$ then the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) $\mathrm{d}x$ is
$$\mathrm{d}\!\left[x(t)\right] = \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}~\mathrm{d}t = \dot{x}~\mathrm{d}t$$